# Build Flat array to Nested tree array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
        const aTree = [{
       "Group": "GroupName1",
       "Act": "100",
       "Work": "Work1",
       "Pname": "Name1",
       "Pvalue": "Value1",
       "Pcount": "10"
    },
    {
       "Group": "GroupName1",
       "Act": "100",
       "Work": "Work1",
       "Pname": "Name2",
       "Pvalue": "Value2",
       "Pcount": "20"
    },
    {
       "Group": "GroupName1",
       "Act": "100",
       "Work": "Work1",
       "Pname": "Name3",
       "Pvalue": "Value3",
       "Pcount": "10"
    },
    {
       "Group": "GroupName1",
       "Act": "400",
       "Work": "Work2",
       "Pname": "Name4",
       "Pvalue": "Value4",
       "Pcount": "2"
    },
    {
       "Group": "GroupName1",
       "Act": "400",
       "Work": "Work2",
       "Pname": "Name5",
       "Pvalue": "Value5",
       "Pcount": "5"
    },
    {
        "Group": "GroupName2",
        "Act": "200",
        "Work": "Work1",
        "Pname": "Name6",
        "Pvalue": "Value6",
        "Pcount": "2"
    },
    {
        "Group": "GroupName2",
        "Act": "200",
        "Work": "Work1",
        "Pname": "Name7",
        "Pvalue": "Value7",
        "Pcount": "14"
    },
    {
       "Group": "GroupName2",
       "Act": "200",
       "Work": "Work1",
       "Pname": "Name8",
       "Pvalue": "Value8",
       "Pcount": "20"
    },
    {
       "Group": "GroupName2",
       "Act": "200",
       "Work": "Work2",
       "Pname": "Name9",
       "Pvalue": "Value9",
       "Pcount": "18"
    },
     {
       "Group": "GroupName3",
       "Act": "200",
       "Work": "Work2",
       "Pname": "Name10",
       "Pvalue": "Value10",
       "Pcount": "15"
    },
     {
       "Group": "GroupName3",
       "Act": "300",
       "Work": "Work1",
       "Pname": "Name11",
       "Pvalue": "Value11",
       "Pcount": "20"
    },
     {
       "Group": "GroupName3",
       "Act": "300",
       "Work": "Work2",
       "Pname": "Name12",
       "Pvalue": "Value12",
       "Pcount": "10"
    },
     
]

var aTree1 = [];
aTree.forEach(function(a) {
    if (!this[a.Group]) {
        this[a.Group] = {
            Tree: {
                GroupName: [{
                    Group: a.Group,
                    Activity: [{
                        Act: a.Act,
                        WorkName: [{
                            Work: a.Work,
                            Planning: [{
                                Qyan1: a.Pname,
                                Quan2: a.Pvalue,
                                Quan3: a.Pcount
                            }]
                        }]
                    }]
                }],

            }
        };

        aTree1.push(this[a.Group]);

    }
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(aTree1);
```

I want the tree structure like below,

```js
[
  [
    "GroupName1",
    [
      [
        100,
        [
          1,
          "foo"
        ],
        [
          2,
          "bar"
        ]
      ],
      [... 400 missing]
    ]
  ],
  [
    "GroupName2",
    [
      [
        200,
        [
          1,
          "foo"
        ],
        [
          2,
          "bar"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ],
  [
    "GroupName3",
    [
      [
        200,
        [
          1,
          "foo"
        ],
        [
          2,
          "bar"
        ]
      ],
      [...300 missing]
    ]
  ]
]
```

```js
 [
      [
        "Group":"GroupName1",
        [
          [
            "Act": "100",
            [
              "PName": "1",
              "PValue": "foo"
            ],
            [
              "PName": 2,
              "PValue":"bar"
            ]
          ],
          [... 400 missing]
        ]
      ],
      [
        "Group":"GroupName2",
        [
          [
            "Act":200,
            [
             "PName": 1,
             "PValue":"foo"
            ],
            [
             "PName": 2,
             "PValue":"bar"
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ],
      [
        "Group":"GroupName3",
        [
          [
            "Act":200,
            [
             "PName": 1,
             "PValue":"foo"
            ],
            [
             "PName": 2,
             "PValue":"bar"
            ]
          ],
          [...300 missing]
        ]
      ]
    ]
```

Comment: What result do you want? You haven't explained what is wrong with the result you're currently getting.

Comment: I want to include the missing part into the array which is mentioned in the screen shot.

Comment: it looks like a multi level grouping. please add the wanted result in litral notation (not an image) to the question.

Comment: @Teemu, i think the question is not about accessing an object.

Comment: Don't post relevant stuff as an image -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @NinaScholz If you've found something I didn't notice, feel free to reopen the question.

Comment: @Teemu, actually not, op has not added a wanted *possible* result.

Comment: I have added expected output sample structure.

Comment: do you really want arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a multi level grouping with an object for faster access to the groups and arrays as result set.

This approach needs two arrays, one for the keys fro grouping in wanted order and another to get the data tupel as result set for the most inner groups.

```js
const
    data = [{ Group: "GroupName1", Act: "100", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name1", Pvalue: "Value1", Pcount: "10" }, { Group: "GroupName1", Act: "100", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name2", Pvalue: "Value2", Pcount: "20" }, { Group: "GroupName1", Act: "100", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name3", Pvalue: "Value3", Pcount: "10" }, { Group: "GroupName1", Act: "400", Work: "Work2", Pname: "Name4", Pvalue: "Value4", Pcount: "2" }, { Group: "GroupName1", Act: "400", Work: "Work2", Pname: "Name5", Pvalue: "Value5", Pcount: "5" }, { Group: "GroupName2", Act: "200", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name6", Pvalue: "Value6", Pcount: "2" }, { Group: "GroupName2", Act: "200", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name7", Pvalue: "Value7", Pcount: "14" }, { Group: "GroupName2", Act: "200", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name8", Pvalue: "Value8", Pcount: "20" }, { Group: "GroupName2", Act: "200", Work: "Work2", Pname: "Name9", Pvalue: "Value9", Pcount: "18" }, { Group: "GroupName3", Act: "200", Work: "Work2", Pname: "Name10", Pvalue: "Value10", Pcount: "15" }, { Group: "GroupName3", Act: "300", Work: "Work1", Pname: "Name11", Pvalue: "Value11", Pcount: "20" }, { Group: "GroupName3", Act: "300", Work: "Work2", Pname: "Name12", Pvalue: "Value12", Pcount: "10" }],
    keys = ['Group', 'Act', 'Work'],
    tupel = ['Pname', 'Pvalue', 'Pcount'],
    result = data
        .reduce((r, o) => {
            keys
                .reduce(function (t, k) {
                    const key = o[k];
                    if (!t[key]) {
                        t[key] = { _: [] };
                        t._.push([key, t[key]._]);
                    }
                    return t[key];
                }, r)
                ._
                .push(tupel.map(k => o[k]));
            return r;
        }, { _: [] })
        ._;
   
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi Nina Scholz, thanks for your reply, Now, im trying to expand my nested tree structure by adding the json format like, [  "GroupName" : "GroupName1" ] [ "Act": "100"]  ["Work": "Work1" ] ["Pname": "Name1", "Pvalue": "Value2", "Pcount": 10]. Is it possible in tree array? kindly sugges.

Comment: if i would know, what data type you want with wanted properties, i could add another solution. but for taking yourself, you just need to replace `[key, t[key]._]` with an object and push a new object instead of `tupel.map(k => o[k])`.

Comment: Hi @Nina-Scholz, i have tried to push the object like you mentioned. But, i'm not new structure which i mentioned in the post. Can you please suggest.

Comment: your given structure is not valid. please add a valid (object with properties) to the question, or better ask a new question.